# Conditional joining Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, database, pandas, join

I'm looking for an optimum way to join two Dataframes where the same record exists in both. Examples would be:

```
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5], "dat1": [34,56,57,45,23]})
dat2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [2,3,4], "dat2": [19,19,20]})

dat1
   id  dat1
0   1    34
1   2    56
2   3    57
3   4    45
4   5    23

dat2
   id  dat2
0   2    19
1   3    19
2   4    20
```

With the aim being to create overall_data:

```
overall_data
   id  dat1  dat2
0   2    56    19
1   3    57    19
2   4    45    20
```

At the moment my method is:

```
dat3 = dat1['id'].isin(dat2['id'])
dat3 = pd.Dataframe(dat3)
dat3.columns = ['bool']
dat4 = dat1.join(dat3)
overall_data = dat4(dat4['bool'] == True)
```

Though this feels very messy. Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the textbook example of an inner join. The most canonical way to have your `id` columns being used for the matching, set them as an index first (here using `inplace` operations to save on extra variable names; depending on your use, you might prefer new copies instead):

```
dat1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
dat2.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Then, the whole operation becomes this simple [join on index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#joining-on-index):

```
>>> overall_data = dat1.join(dat2, how='inner')
>>> overall_data

    dat1  dat2
id
2     56    19
3     57    19
4     45    20
```

If you do **not** want to modify the original DataFrames, you can use utility function [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) instead, which performs the same operation, but needs the common column name specified explicitely:

```
>>>  pd.merge(dat1, dat2, how='inner', on='id')

   id  dat1  dat2
0   2    56    19
1   3    57    19
2   4    45    20
```

Comment: @SebSquire: please consider to accept (checkmark symbol below the vote counter of) this answer, if it has answered the question to your satisfaction. ;-)